# How to make FileInputStream and FileOutputStream in a java class

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I wrote two methods to write and read data from Internal Storage, now that I want to put them in a non activity class I get errors at `openFileOutput` and `openFileInput` that says the method `openFileInput`/`openFileOutput` is undefined for the type IOstream(name of my class)

I don't know how to fix it.

```
public void write(String fileName, String content) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream outStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outStream.write(content.getBytes());
    outStream.close();
}

public String read(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream inStream = openFileInput(fileName);

    String content = null;
    byte[] readByte = new byte[inStream.available()];

    while(inStream.read(readByte) != -1){
        content = new String(readByte);
    }
    inStream.close();
    return content;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to put these methods in their own class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post a question and say "I get errors", actually posting said errors would go a long way to show people your problem.

Taking a guess from your question and code, you've moved those methods to a class that does not extend Context, where those two methods are declared, so they can't be found.

You need a reference to a context to be able to access those methods.

```
public void write(Context context, String fileName, String content) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream outStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outStream.write(content.getBytes());
    outStream.close();
}

public String read(Context context, String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream inStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);

    String content = null;
    byte[] readByte = new byte[inStream.available()];

    while(inStream.read(readByte) != -1){
        content = new String(readByte);
    }
    inStream.close();
    return content;
}
```

Comment: @Seinmon Once again you have posted a statement with no information in it. 'Didn't work' is not a problem description. If you want an answer you need to ask a proper question.